# How to consume SOAP with Angular 4?

Tags: angular, soap, https, cors

I need to access a web-service from a different domain in a secure way with Angular 4. The web-service (.Net C#)  as well as the Angular client are under my control (i.e. both can be modified by me).

According to my (limited) understanding I need CORS for the xDomain access from the browser and HTTPS for the security. I found no way to realize this with a REST web-service. Therefore I think I need SOAP.

How should I use SOAP from an Angular 4 webpage? Is there a similar approach available like the "HttpClient" (from '@angular/common/http') for REST?

I found two approaches, but both seem to be not quite "Angular-conform":

1. [Integrate JQuery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WUzs1XraPU)
2. [Use pure Javascript (using xdr)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk2Vz9kSVYQ)

Thank you for your help in advance!

Burkhard